# How to create loadbalancer (IAAS) in Azure for Kubernetes Ingress controller

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-load-balancer

I created Kubernetes cluster using ACS-engine in Azure and installed Ingress controller.

I deployed a service:

- Inside the cluster running the command curl :/myservice give the expected response.

I created a VM with NGinx in order to get external access and using the external IP of the VM such external access to the service exists.

My Goal:

- Replace the VM with Azure IAAS Loadbalancer.

Steps that i did using the UI:

1. Click Create resources -> Create public IP address -> set name of the IP -> set assignment Static -> define the resource group.
2. Click create resources -> Networking -> Load Balancer -> select the publicip that created in step #1 -> Use the same resource group.
3. Created Health probe -> protocol HTTP, port 32597 (Ingress port) and path /myservice
4. Defined the backend pool to the Availabilityset of the Kubernetes nodes (agents).
5. Created Inbound NAT rule:
   Service: Custom.
   Port: 32597.
   Availabilityset: Kubernetes nodes (agents)

Unlike the VM i cannot reach the website and i do not see in the Loadbalncer logs any information.

Questions:

1. How to get the traffic logs ?
2. Can i run TCPDUMP ?
3. How to fix the issue ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know, if you want to reach the website in Azure Kubernets Cluster through Load Balancer, you should set Load Balancer rules, not NAT rules. And the rules screenshot here.
[image]

> How to get the traffic logs ?

You can use the command `kubectl logs azure-vote-front-7976b7dcd9-m7445` like this to get the pods logs. You can get more details from [`kubectl logs podName`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#logs). And the test screenshot here.
[image]

> Can i run TCPDUMP ?

If you want to run TCPDUMP in the Kubernets node, you can ssh into the node and run TCPDUMP with the root permission. And the test screenshot here.
[image]

For your third question, you can follow the suggestion which I say at the beginning.

Comment: The solution works in 2 ways: the first one is as suggested create loadbalancer using the UI. the second one is changing the type of the instead of NodePort to Loadbalancer.

Comment: @OronGolan If the answer is helpful, you can accept it as an answer so that help others who look for this.